# Handling exceptions for positive integer numbers

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I want to return the value passed to this method if it's a positive integer value. If not I want to throw exceptions, which I am catching in my main method, where the program is exited then.

```
 private String posInteger(String input) {
        try {
            if (Integer.valueOf(input) >= 0) {
                return input;
            } else {
                throw new MyOwnExampleException("Error, number can't be negative.");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new MyOwnExampleException("Error, number must be an integervalue.");
        }
    }
```

I don't like the fact that I am throwing `MyOwnExampleException` in the try block and then again in the catch block. Is there a better way to this? I definitely want to throw my own exception.

Comment: Why don't you like it? They are two completely different cases.

Comment: You could just throw the NumberFormatException and ditch the try-catch block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with throwing a second of your kind of exception in the same method.  They are two different causes, with two different messages.  Besides, at most one of them can be thrown in one invocation of your method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class MyOwnExampleException extends Exception
{
    MyOwnExampleException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}
class himansh
{
    static private String posInteger(String input) throws MyOwnExampleException 
    {
        if (Integer.valueOf(input) >= 0)
            {
                return input;
            }
        else 
            {
                throw new MyOwnExampleException("Error, number can't be negative.");
            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String h;
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       String s=sc.next();
       try
       {
           h=himansh.posInteger(s);
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           return;
       }
       System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: please consider formatting your code as it is very difficult to follow and it does not align with best practices.